# Replacing app setting with environment variable in Sitecore managed cloud

Tags: docker, aks, sitecore-managed-cloud

Can someone tell me whether it's possible to replace an app setting with an environment variable in Sitecore Managed Cloud?  Specifically, we would like to create some rule-based config based on an app setting that changes in each environment.

Comment: Are you on containers or app services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i thought i would post the answer to this in case anyone else comes across this problem.

So the Sitecore 10.2 docker images (this is the only version I have verified this against) come with a configbuilder that lets you update app settings using environment variables.

If you look in the web.config you will find the config builder settings

```
<add name="SitecoreAppSettingsBuilder" mode="Strict" prefix="SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_" stripPrefix="true"
    type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
```

You can create environment variables with the same name as the appsetting prefixed with SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_ and at runtime the app settings value will be replaced with the one in the environment variable.

Answer (score -2):

- I am assuming you are familiar with creating rule-based configuration. [Sitecore documentation covers this extensively](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-rule-based-configuration.html)
- Sitecore have outlined steps you can follow to [configure your Managed Cloud instance](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/managed-cloud/configure-managed-cloud.html)
- What you are looking for is creating a custom image where you can define your rule-based configurations. You can store your custom image into AZR that is provisioned as part of the SC managed cloud infrastructure. Then update the `docker-images.json` file with the new image. Below are the steps:

> 1. Build a new version of an image based on an existing Sitecore image.
> 2. Push your image to Private ACR.
>    Update the docker-images.json file with the new image.
> 3. To change docker-images.json, you must [create a pull request to main](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/managed-cloud/trigger-the-infrastructure-and-application-pipelines-automatically.html).

Comment: thanks Julius but that's not what i'm after really.  Specifically im interested in how you replace an app setting with an environment variable so i can use that value in my rule based config